# High memory consumption

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a iOS app developed using xamarin forms . It works fine with all other devices except a iPad mini iOS version 11.2 . I have tried reinstalling the app and the problem persists . I have now upgraded the OS version to iOS version 12 and the problem still persists.The issue is not reproducible in other devices.

Comment: Without any problemmatic code and/or what is causing the memory problem, how can anyone help? Try starting with the Xamarin Profiler to determine the root cause of the memory consumption: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/

Comment: I tried the xamarin profiler everything looks fine. I tried instruments as well the memory consumption is within limits. The issue occurs only on a specific tablet at client end and is not reproducible on other ipad mini with the same OS version.Is it a device issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a device issue. Hardware reset solved the issue.

You can do Hard reset of your iPad by holding down both the Home and sleep/wake buttons simultaneously until your iPad goes to black and restarts with Apple logo, then release the buttons.